# Join multiple table with one table in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, join

I know that I can use with() in eloquent but I need run only on query.

please help me how to join two or more table with one table.

I'm using laratables and I'm trying to show likes count.

I'm trying to built that but getting problem :(

```
$roles = \DB::table('table0')
        ->leftJoin('table1', 'table0.id', '=', 'table1.table_id')
        ->leftJoin('table2', 'table0.id', '=', 'table2.table_id')
        ->select('table0.id', \DB::raw('COUNT(table1.id) as table1_count, COUNT(table2.id) as table2_count'))
        ->groupBy('table0.id');
```

for getting better information about my problem and also my wish you can see this picture bellow.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezHBr.png)

Comment: does this answer your question? - https://kirschbaumdevelopment.com/news-articles/adding-some-laravel-magic-to-your-eloquent-joins

Comment: COUNT calculation when multiple JOINs are used gives wrong results due to "join multiplying". Use `COUNT(DISTINCT tableN.id)` at least (if rows count per table is high then this method will be too expensive, use counting subqueries instead)..

Comment: Thank you Akina . Yes my problem is that not use DISTINCT.